# Best approach to concurrency issue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a `Person` that I am trying to populate.  Many of the setter methods take time to populate since the data is supplied from DB calls that can take some time (over 10 seconds) to return.

I am looking for the best way to populate my mutators asynchronously before returning my `Person` back to the calling method.

Here's an example:

```
Person p = service.getPersonById(id);
// populate from DMV DB
p.setTickets(dmvService.getTicketsById(id));  // takes 15 seconds to return data
p.setAccidentRecord(dmvService.getAccidentsById(id));  // takes 10 seconds.
...
...

return p;
```

I would like to be able to run my methods (`setTickets`, `setAccidentRecord`, etc) asynchronously to reduce my load time down from over 25 seconds to around 15.

Comment: the provided answer is perfect, but you could still look at RxJava (Observable)

Answer (score 2):

[`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)<sup>†</sup>, introduced in Java 8, is just the ticket. It is a monadic, chainable class that makes it easy to manage off-thread computations.

A future represents a computation that will finish and yield a result some time in the future. It may have already completed, or it may take a while in some background thread. `CompletableFuture` builds on this core concept by letting you attach all kinds of additional transformations and handlers to an existing future.

```
Person p = service.getPersonById(id);

CompletableFuture.allOf(
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dmvService.getTicketsById(id))
                     .thenAccept(p::setTickets),

    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dmvService.getAccidentsById(id))
                     .thenAccept(p::setAccidentRecord)
).join();

return p;
```

In your case, you can use [`supplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-) to run `getTicketsById` and `getAccidentsById` in background threads. Since you want to call the corresponding setters when those methods return, you use [`thenAccept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-) to say, "when that method returns, supply the value to this setter".

You have two background computations and you don't want to return until both of them complete. Wrapping both of those futures into a bigger one with [`allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) gets us there. The `allOf` future doesn't itself complete until the two inner futures are both completed.

Finally, we [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--) the `allOf` future, which waits for it to finish before proceeding. If any of this code might throw an exception then `join` will throw that exception itself—although it'll be wrapped in a `CompletionException`—so you can add a try/catch around it if you wish.

---

<sup>†</sup>Unfortunately, Java's first stab at this concept, `Future`, is an underpowered, lackluster class. They got it right with `CompletableFuture`, but `Future` stole the ideal name.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  I will give it a whirl tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: Before going into production, it should be clarified whether invoking `getTicketsById` and `getAccidentsById` concurrently on the same `dmvService` instance is value, i.e. whether the implementation is thread safe and whether it has an actual benefit; the same for invoking `setTickets` and `setAccidentRecord` concurrently on the same `Person` instance. It’s also not clear whether the `dmvService` queries or the `Person`’s setter are the actual bottleneck. Unfortunately, database drivers often achieve thread safety by serializing the operations, which reduces the usefulness of concurrency…

Comment: When I tried implementing this I kept getting errors that the `dmvService` was managed in another session and there's currently no session available